# adopted tag - image only visible to me

Tags: bug, tags, unicoins, april-fools

I just adopted the `ruby-on-rails` tag (on SO) with some of my Unicoins, but the account of my brother does not show my proud purchase.

Please fix this.

Comment: Look out, I think your brother is laughing behind your back.

Comment: It's just in beta stage. There will be fix for it soon.

Comment: All fixes are scheduled for April 2nd

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for information on how to solve this issue. This fix will work every time, guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Lambeosaurus and things with noodley-appendages and related animals may not be visible to all people in all places.